# Merge two pandas dataframes by index and replace column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

DF1

```
index = np.arange('2020-01-01 00:00', '2020-01-01 00:04', dtype='datetime64[m]')
df = np.random.randint(100,500, size=(4,4))
columns =['Open','High','Low','Close']
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=index, columns = columns)
df.index.name = 'Time'

                     Open  High  Low  Close
Time                                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00   266   397  177    475
2020-01-01 00:01:00   362   135  456    235
2020-01-01 00:02:00   315   298  296    493
2020-01-01 00:03:00   324   411  198    101
```

DF2

```
index = np.arange('2020-01-01 00:02', '2020-01-01 00:05', dtype='datetime64[m]')
df2 = np.random.randint(100,500, size=(3,4))
columns =['Open','High','Low','Close']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, index=index, columns = columns)
df2.index.name = 'Time'

                     Open  High  Low  Close
Time                                       
2020-01-01 00:02:00   430   394  131    490
2020-01-01 00:03:00   190   211  394    359
2020-01-01 00:04:00   192   291  143    350
```

I need to merge both dataframes by the index (Time) and replace the column values of DF1 by the column values of DF2.

This is my expected output:

```
                     Open  High  Low  Close
Time                                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00   266   397  177    475 ->>>> Correspond to DF1
2020-01-01 00:01:00   362   135  456    235 ->>>> Correspond to DF1
2020-01-01 00:02:00   430   394  131    490 ->>>> Correspond to DF2
2020-01-01 00:03:00   190   211  394    359 ->>>> Correspond to DF2
2020-01-01 00:04:00   192   291  143    350 ->>>> Correspond to DF2
```

I have try several functions including merge or concat (concat([df1, df2], join="inner")) but with no success. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df2.combine_first(df)
```

```
                     Open  High  Low  Close
Time                                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00   266   397  177    475
2020-01-01 00:01:00   362   135  456    235
2020-01-01 00:02:00   430   394  131    490
2020-01-01 00:03:00   190   211  394    359
2020-01-01 00:04:00   192   291  143    350
```

Because you mentioned `pd.concat`, here is how you could do it with that.

```py
out = pd.concat([df, df2])
out = out[~out.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
print(out)
```

```
                     Open  High  Low  Close
Time                                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00   266   397  177    475
2020-01-01 00:01:00   362   135  456    235
2020-01-01 00:02:00   430   394  131    490
2020-01-01 00:03:00   190   211  394    359
2020-01-01 00:04:00   192   291  143    350
```